# Return statement with brackets

Tags: javascript, validation, return, brackets

I was looking in a Javascript validation form when I found this:

```
return (!firstNameError && !lastNameError && !emailError && !phoneError && !address1Error && !cityError && !stateError && !countryError && !zipError && !cdlError)
```

What does these brackets mean?

Comment: there is no brackets {...}

Comment: If you are referring to parentheses, they are not required here since all operators are the same.  But are nice for readability.  However, if you are mixing ANDs and ORs, they are used to enforce precedence when the default of resolving ANDs first then ORs won't cut it.

Answer (score 4):

The parenthesis in the return statement indicates that it must return the boolean value for all the statements inside. In this case it will return false unless every variable inside the parenthesis is false (ie no error was triggered among all the potential errors).

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: @Peter Daniel is right the return is checking for a boolean value true/false, in this case your checking multiple variables (firstNameError) if it has a value... but you also have an exclamation "!" which means NOT... So for example return(!firstNameError) is stating if the value for the variable (firstNameError) does NOT exist, then return TRUE. Now for your code above your checking multiple variables to see if they have values and your using the && operator so your checking if ALL variables don't have values then return TRUE else if one variable has a value then it will return FALSE.

Comment: Um metal-gogo it says to avoid comments like 'thanks' and '+1'.